# Height of image in the first column of the same picture is slightly taller than all other columns, CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 5 columns that stores images inside each column. The image width is 100% relative to the td, and the image height is proportional to its width. I stored around 25 pictures of the same image, and I'm using the table to show those pictures in columns of 5. The problem is that the picture in the first column's height is always slightly taller than the height of the pictures in the other four columns, even though they're of the same image. Please take a look at my code below:

```
<style>
img {
width: 100%;
}
table,td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<?php

include('all.php'); //includes all the necessary functions;

$picture = gd("image/images"); //get image reference link from database and store in multi-dimensional array;
$count = count($picture); //return number of reference links

echo "<table>";
while ($count > 0) {

$tempCount = 0;

echo "<tr>";

while ($tempCount < 5) {

if ($count > 0) {
$count--;
$temp = $picture[$count][0];
echo "<td><img src = 'uploads/$temp'></td>";
}
$tempCount++;

}

echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Sorry but dynamic code won't help us. Grab the generated HTML and setup a demo.

Comment: we need html and css to be able to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by setting the width of the td to 20%.

```
<style>
img {
width: 100%;
}
table,td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
width: 20%;
}
</style>
```